# to save editable content in database

Tags: cakephp

I am cakephp newbie.I have one table echo'ed in view .Every table cell in this table is editable for example on the double clicking the cell input box appears ..this is being done with jquery plugin..Now problem is how should I save entered value in input box in the database..Please reply.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cakephp 1.3 or greater you could use included an Adapter based helper, and included 3 of the most requested libraries. Prototype/Scriptaculous, Mootools/Mootools-more, and jQuery/jQuery UI.

Check out this link

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1593/Methods

You could combine (onchange)event and request(post data to url) methods to save data to your database.

Hope that helps.